# Alert dialog is not being displayed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

Im trying to make an alert dialog when a Preference on the preferenceScreen is tapped.

My code is as follows:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NotNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()));
        builder.setMessage(R.string.are_you_sure);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //something
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //something
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

I created an object from this class and called the `show()` method, but after running the application and tapping on the preference, nothing happens.

Here is my other class:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable String rootKey){
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs, rootKey);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sp, String key){
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        AlertDialogFragment alert = new AlertDialogFragment();
        if(key.equals("logout")){
            if (manager != null) {
                alert.show(manager, "tag");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that `manager` is not null?

Comment: How do you know `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` is executing?

Comment: Ahh, I dont know if onSharedPreferenceChanged() is executing at all. I thought it executes when I change a Preference which Im doing by taping on it after programe is compiled

Comment: Yes, it does execute when you _change_ a preference, but just because you're tapping on it doesn't mean you're changing it. Here's a hint: Use a breakpoint, use `Log.d()`. You can determine what is executing, and what is not.

Comment: problem has been solved. thank you all guys :).